# Convert FirestoreCollection into an array?

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having difficulty converting the Firestore data into an array for the chart.js graph.

**Getting the data from Firestore**

```
fetchData(){

    //Get data
    this.updatesCollection = this.afs.collection(pathStats);

    this.updates = this.updatesCollection.valueChanges();
}
```

**Creating the Chart**

```
createChart(){

this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['5/18/18', '5/19/18', '5/20/18', '5/21/18', '5/22/18', '5/23/18'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Filled',
      backgroundColor: 'gray',
      data: [4, 3, 5, 2, 6, 7],
      fill: true,
    }]
  },
    }
)
```

I'm using the hard-coded values `[4, 3, 5, 2, 6, 7]` right now as a placeholder for my data points. How would I use the values coming from Firestore instead?

**Solution**

As mentioned by Ohad below:

```
let chartData;

this.updatesCollection.ref.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    chartData = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
}
```

This gets you an array with each document in it's own index. You can access individual properties like any other object (ie `chartData[0].wheelCount`).

Comment: How your data pulling out from firestore looks like?

Comment: @FiringBlanks Where exactly did you put this snippet? It seems that when I try to use the `chartData` as the `data` in the `datasets`, I got an error saying that the `chartData` didn't exist. Every way I'm trying to replicate this isn't working. I think I'm missing something very basic.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Calling `this.updatesCollection.get()` will asynchronously return a `querySnapshot` object.

A `querySnapshot` has a `docs` property which is an array containing zero or more `documentSnapshot` objects. The data in these can be extracted with the `.data()` method.

The code for producing your array could look like this:

```
let chartData = this.updates.collection.get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    chartData = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
  })
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this somewhere in the docs or you just knew to map doc to doc.data()?